# Javascript Replace - Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to replace a code example: OD3 - The first must always be alpha character, 2nd alphanumeric and the last must always be numeric. What's the `regular expression` to check and `replace` the first and regulate the rest to enter correctly? A user could enter in the number 0 instead of the letter O, so I want to correct it immediately...

this is what I have so far: `onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-z]/g,'')`

Comment: What do you mean by - *regulate the rest to enter correctly*?

Comment: What should happen if it's not correct? Blank out the value? Also how many replacements are there, is it just `0`=`O` ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest just indicating the error to a user instead of replacing the values. Something like

```
oninput="if (! /^[a-z][a-z0-9]\d$/i.test(this.value) ) displayMessage('incorrect code');"
```

If you definitely have to replace the value on the fly, you could do somthing like that:

```
oninput='validateValue()';
...
function validateValue() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (! /[a-z]/i.test(val[0]) this.value = '';
    else if (! /[a-z0-9]/i.test(val[1]) this.value = val.slice(0,1);
    else if (! /\d/.test(val[2]) this.value = val.slice(0,2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better have like this.

```
onkeyup="testRegex(this.value)";
```

It is not `.replace()` it is `.test()`

```
function testRegex(value) {
   if(value.test(/[^a-zA-z]/g)) {
       alert("Please enter correct value");
       return false;
    }
}
```